# Read List<double> from Json via Newtonsoft in C#

Tags: c#, json

I would like to read a JSON string via the Newtonsoft Json library. It works fine for any basic datatype, but it does not work for a `List<double>` or any `List` for that matter.

The test application looks like the following:

```
static void main()
{
  string jsonString = @"
            {
                'name': 'set1',
                'Xvv': {
                         'parameter': 'hByT',
                         'values': '[1,2,3]'
                    }
            }";
  JObject Json = JObject.Parse(jsonString);

  var name = Json["name"].ToString();
  var data = Json["Xvv"]["values"].Value<List<double> >(); // Raises error
}
```

The last line throws the following exception:

> System.InvalidCastException: Invalid cast from 'System.String' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List

Is there a way to access the data directly as a `List<double>`?

Comment: Could you clarify what you want to happen vs what's happening with your current code? It's not clear to me what you're looking for in this question. (I wouldn't personally use an interpolated string here - you're not using any interpolation, and it means doubling braces. I'd also probably use apostrophes instead of double quotes, followed by a `.Replace('\'', '"')` at the end. It makes the JSON easier to read.)

Comment: I've updated the entire question, as it makes much more sense now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the example JSON you've provided, `values` is a string. A proper JSON array would be

```
'values': [1,2,3]
```

Anyway, after changing the string to the array, `.Value<List<double>>()` would throw an exception, that a `JArray` cannot be cast to a `JToken` - unfortunately I do not really know, *why* it does not work.

However, `JToken.ToObject<T>` does the trick, it

> Creates an instance of the specified .NET type from the JToken

([see the documentation for ToObject](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_ToObject__1_1.htm))

With the line

```cs
var data = Json["Xvv"]["values"].ToObject<List<double>>();
```

you can cast the array correctly.

If an `IEnumerable` would be fine for you, too, you could also use

```cs
var data = Json["Xvv"]["values"].Values<double>();
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I've been banging my head against a wall for the last 6 hours.